# Can't seem to be able to merge 2 arrays as i want it to into a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I've got two pieces of code that i want to merge to one array to export to a csv file the purpose is that i first get info from the desktop(getting make, model, serial,...) which i put into an array like this:

```
$outputArray = @()

foreach($computer in $Desktop){

    $output = [Ordered]@{
        "Merk" = $Desktop.CsManufacturer
        "Model" = $Desktop.CsModel
        "S/n" = $Desktop.BiosSeralNumer
    }
    $outputArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $output

}
```

The second piece is that i wanna retrieve all monitor information from the connected monitors to my device:

```
$outputArrayMon = @()

    Write-host 
    ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors)
    {
        $Manufacturer = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
        $Name = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName                     | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""
        $Serial = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID         -notmatch 0 | ForEach{[char]$_}) -join ""

        $output = [Ordered]@{
            "Merk /Model" = $Manufacturer
            "Type" = $Name
            "S/n" = $Serial
        }

    $outputArrayMon += New-Object PSObject -Property $output

}
```

I am trying to merge them like this and export it to a csv file

```
$outputArrayRES = $outputArray + $outputArrayMon

$outputArrayRES | Export-Csv -Path $GL\info.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When i export to a text file my results are very normal and clear but i can't figure out how to get it to work in a csv file, here is an example of my output in the csv file(there is more output but its just to make the post a bit cleaner):

[image: csv output]

The problem is that i don't even receive some values in the csv file correctly that i do receive in the textfile.

The way i want it to work is that every value has to be on the same line in the CSV file. instead of on 4 seperate lines i want 2 1 = the variables and 2 = the values of the variables

EDIT(1):

Weird monitor values in my output file

```
";""
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

EDIT(2):

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
            "Merk" = $Desktop.CsManufacturer
            "Model" = $Desktop.CsModel
            "S/n" = $Desktop.BiosSeralNumer
            "PC Naam" = $Desktop.CsName
            "CPU" = $processor.Name
            "Memory" = "$RAM GB"
            "OS" = $Desktop.WindowsProductName
            "MAC LAN" = $MACLAN
            "MAC WIFI" = $MACWIFI
            "Office" = $officeVersion
            "Merk /Model" = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName -notmatch 0 | ForEach-Object{[char]$_}) -join ""
            "Type" = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName         -notmatch 0 | ForEach-Object{[char]$_}) -join ""
            "SerialScherm" = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID         -notmatch 0 | ForEach-Object{[char]$_}) -join ""

}
```

Comment: Please show us where the variables for monitors are coming from. If they are all empty as you have commented, then there's the problem..

Comment: I put the remaining code for the monitors in the post.

Comment: Update i'm getting the variables now i made a minor mistake myself i saw, its just a matter of getting everything in the output i want now but the main problem is solved thanks!

Comment: @Theo One last question is it possible to output everything without a header? that i can just import these values instantly in another file?

Comment: If you really want to output without headers, you can change the `Export-Csv` cmd into `ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
Set-Content -Path $outputFile`.

Comment: @Theo Every time i have more than 1 monitor now all of the computer info gets put in the CSV file again with every new monitor do you know a way to append the Nth monitor on the same row as the PC in the same file?

Comment: If you need more clarification i can send you a picture of the output if you like

Comment: You can only do this if you add more columns for each monitor (maybe 4 or five), so you get `"Monitor 1 Merk /Model"`, `"Monitor 1 Type"`, `"Monitor 1 Serial"`, `"Monitor 2 Type"`, `"Monitor 2 Type"`, `"Monitor 2 Serial"`, etc. I see you still use `-notmatch` for constructing the monitor strings from the UInt16 array. By doing so, you will lose characters. Use `-ne` instead.

Comment: I have added code for putting monitor(s) info in the same row as the computer info.

Comment: P.S. Are you sure about the spelling of property `BiosSeralNumer` ??

Comment: @Theo I found a solution myself, and yes that was a typo from my side, Thanks for the incredible help though i'm still new to powershell and you helped me out alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine the two `foreach` loops and create `PSCustomObject`s like [bunzab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3866560/bunzab) answered, but with the properties for the both the computer and its monitor(s) combined.

```
# assuming $Desktop is an array of computer names
$Desktop    = @('pc1','pc2','pc3')
$outputFile = '<PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE OUTPUT CSV FILE>'

$info = foreach($computer in $Desktop) {
    # get the info you want for this computer. You didn't state HOW you did that, probably using Get-ComputerInfo.
    # On my Windows 7 machine this still fails with error:
    # Unable to find an entry point named 'GetFirmwareType' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'
    # so I used these commands instead:

    $pcInfo   = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer
    $biosInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computer

    # store these properties for later use
    $pcName         = $pcInfo.Name
    $pcManufacturer = $pcInfo.Manufacturer
    $pcModel        = $pcInfo.Model
    $pcBiosSN       = $biosInfo.SerialNumber

    # next get the monitor info for this computer
    $Monitors = Get-WmiObject -Class WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName $computer
    foreach($monitor in $Monitors) {
        # emit a PSCustomObject with all properties combined
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Computer Naam'       = $pcName
            'Computer Merk'       = $pcManufacturer
            'Computer Model'      = $pcModel
            'BIOS S/N'            = $pcBiosSN
            "Monitor Merk /Model" = ($Monitor.ManufacturerName -ne 0 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } ) -join ''
            "Monitor Naam"        = ($Monitor.UserFriendlyName -ne 0 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } ) -join ''
            "Monitor S/N"         = ($Monitor.SerialNumberID   -ne 0 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } ) -join ''
        }
    }
} 

$info | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Hope this helps

<sup>Note: looking at the screenshot, I can see you double-clicked the output CSV file to open it in Excel, but your current locale (NL) then puts everything in the first column.
This is why I have added `-Delimiter ';'`. You could also have used the `-UseCulture` switch if you are running this on the same machine you are double-clicking the output CSV file on.</sup>

---

**Edit**

---

In your latest comment you say you want the monitor info in the same row as the computer info. This means adding more columns to the output CSV if the computer has multiple monitors.
If that is what is needed, use this code below:

```
# assuming $Desktop is an array of computer names
$Desktop    = @('pc1','pc2','pc3')
$outputFile = '<PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE OUTPUT CSV FILE>'

$info = foreach($computer in $Desktop) {
    # get the info you want for this computer. You didn't state HOW you did that, probably using Get-ComputerInfo.
    # On my Windows 7 machine this still fails with error:
    # Unable to find an entry point named 'GetFirmwareType' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'
    # so I used these commands instead:

    $pcInfo   = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer
    $biosInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Bios -ComputerName $computer

    # create a PSCustomObject with all properties combined
    # first add computer properties. (insert more when needed)
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Computer Naam'  = $pcInfo.Name
        'Computer Merk'  = $pcInfo.Manufacturer
        'Computer Model' = $pcInfo.Model
        'BIOS S/N'       = $biosInfo.SerialNumber
    }
    # next get the monitor info for this computer
    $Monitors = @(Get-WmiObject -Class WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi -ComputerName $computer)
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Monitors.Count; $i++) {
        # add monitor properties to the object
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor $($i + 1) Merk /Model" -Value (($Monitors[$i].ManufacturerName -ne 0 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } ) -join '')
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor $($i + 1) Naam"        -Value (($Monitors[$i].UserFriendlyName -ne 0 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } ) -join '')
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Monitor $($i + 1) Serienummer" -Value (($Monitors[$i].SerialNumberID   -ne 0 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ } ) -join '')
    }
    # output the object
    $obj
} 

$info | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Force
```

Comment: The layout of the file is alot better already thanks for that but i'm still not getting the values for my monitors right in my file they are literally empty like this: 
";""
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

using this code now (put all of the retrieving info commands in variables and its in dutch but it shouldn't be that confusing i hope)

code will be in the bottom of my post

Comment: @claeys please don't put code in a comment. Edit your question instead and paste it there in a formatted fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom object instead. It will give you the headings in your csv when you export it too:

```
$outputArray = @()

foreach($computer in $Desktop){

    $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Merk = $Desktop.CsManufacturer
        Model = $Desktop.CsModel
        S/n = $Desktop.BiosSeralNumer
    }
    $outputArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $output

}
```